# Django nginx gunicorn 502 bad gateway

Tags: django, nginx, server, web-deployment

I was deploying my Django project on fedora 33 nginx server. But domain and localhost tell me 502 bad gateway. I made diagnostic and learned that:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)  
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-01-08 01:34:08 +04; 1min 17s ago
   Process: 4348 ExecStart=/home/robot/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3
    --bind unix:/home/robot/plagiat/plagiat.sock plagiat.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 4348 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC) CPU: 5ms
   
Jan 08 01:34:10 baku systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.      
Jan 08 01:34:10 baku systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.                                                  
Jan 08 01:34:10 baku systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.                                                           
Jan 08 01:34:10 baku systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.      
Jan 08 01:34:11 baku systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.                                                  
Jan 08 01:34:11 baku systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.                                                           
Jan 08 01:34:11 baku systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon. 
Jan 08 01:34:11 baku systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly. 
Jan 08 01:34:11 baku systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
Jan 08 01:34:11 baku systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
```

Comment: Have you checked `/home/robot/plagiat/plagiat.sock` to see if the sock exists?

Comment: this file is not exist (( what i need do ? i was using digitalocean's manual https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file